# React Native and Firebase - Email and Password Authentication

Tags: firebase, react-native

I am working on an Application that will be using an Authentication method to login specific users. I am looking to have a page directly after login, where it will say "Welcome back, (Insert users name here). I understand that Firebase does not incorporate any sort of Name with a login.

How would you recommend I accomplish this?

LoginForm.js

```
<Card style={{ marginBottom: 200 }}>
        <CardSection style={styles.inputStyle}>
          <Input
            label="Email"
            placeholder="Username"
            onChangeText={this.onEmailChange.bind(this)}
            value={this.props.email}
          />
        </CardSection>
        <CardSection style={styles.inputStyle}>
          <Input
            secureTextEntry
            label="Password"
            placeholder="Password"
            onChangeText={this.onPasswordChange.bind(this)}
            value={this.props.password}
          />
        </CardSection>

        {this.renderError()}

        <CardSection style={styles.inputStyle}>
          {this.renderButton()}
        </CardSection>
      </Card>
```

Comment: Could you store a name in the `Firebase` database associated with each user that's returned on login?

Comment: I am attempting to figure out how to do so, I believe there may be a way utilizing `Firebase CLI` to add an attribute that way.